# Continue running the code after folder interaction

Tags: vba, excel

I  have a short procedure that renames a file before uploading it to our processing tool, unfortunately the file is in a password protected .zip file (we can't use the standard extraction, it's company policy that we must use SecureZip) so I need to extract it before the script can interact with it. I know how to open a folder with vba, but how would I go about continuing the code after I close the folder? I have the following code so far:

```
Sub Extract_Rename()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim OldName As String
Dim NewName As String

OldName = "REPORTS2xxxx.SCR0400." & mGlobalDate & ".txt" 'define default file name
NewName = "123456_GR_xxxx_ALL_xxxx_modules_" & mGlobalDate & ".txt" 'define new file name
FolderPath = "C:\Users\" 'define source folder path

    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus 'open source folder to extract the file from .zip archive

    On Error GoTo Quit

        Name "C:\Users\" & OldName As "C:\Users\" & NewName 'rename file

Quit:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without user interaction. I can imagine 2 possible solutions.

1. User has to press a button for renaming which calls another sub for the renaming part.
2. We let pop up a message box which halts the code until the user confirms that he unzipped the file.

Here is the example for the second solution:

```
Option Explicit 'see note below

Public Sub Extract_Rename()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim OldName As String
    Dim NewName As String

    OldName = "REPORTS2xxxx.SCR0400." & mGlobalDate & ".txt" 'define default file name
    NewName = "123456_GR_xxxx_ALL_xxxx_modules_" & mGlobalDate & ".txt" 'define new file name
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\" 'define source folder path

    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus 'open source folder to extract the file from .zip archive

    'this msgbox stops the code until the user presses OK
    If Not MsgBox("Please unzip the file, when finished press OK to proceed.", _
      vbOKCancel + vbExclamation) = vbOK Then GoTo Quit

    On Error GoTo Quit
    Name "C:\Users\" & OldName As "C:\Users\" & NewName 'rename file

Quit:

End Sub
```

Note: You should use `Option Explicit`. Your variable `Foldername` is not declared but you probably meant to use `FolderPath` instead. If you use `Option Explicit` these issues cannot happen anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't proceed with renaming the file (no error message), I also tried switching the `Then GoTo Quit` to `Then Resume Next` after `vbOK` but it still doesn't work.  My variables are all over the place, as I use global variables across multiple modules, and I just copied this module and tried renaming the variables, but thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: did you debug the code step-by-step (running it with F8)? What happens? Also comment out `On Error GoTo Quit` to debug, otherwise you won't see any errors.

Comment: Yeah, it was a "File Not Found" error, was an issue with the date format in the filename. Now the code works perfectly! I left 'Then Resume Next' in after `vbOK`, otherwise it would just jump to the `Quit:` line right? Thank you so much for the help either way.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr It will `GoTo Quit` only if the user presses `Cancel` or the `X` (see the `If NOT … = vbOK`) so if it is ok then the code continues to the next line. What you did `Then Resume Next` dosen't work.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so it's just error handling. Thought it was necessary to proceed for some reason.  Thanks for clarifying! (still learning you see)

Comment: @Rhyfelwr It is necessary for NOT to proceed (when user clicks something else than OK, like Cancel or X. So you can get out of this without throwing an error.